# How to get two lists from one table using one-to-many relation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I have a table called RR. In which there will be two sets of values. My table is

```
CREATE TABLE "TSL_RR_CONFIGURATION"
  (
    "ID"                       NUMBER(19,0),
    "TRK_TYPE"                 VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
    "MEASURE_SYSTEM"           VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
    "MIN_LENGTH"               NUMBER,
    "MAX_LENGTH"               NUMBER,
    "MIN_WIDTH"                NUMBER,
    "MAX_WIDTH"                NUMBER,
    "MIN_HEIGHT"               NUMBER,
    "MAX_HEIGHT"               NUMBER,
    "MIN_WEIGHT"               NUMBER,
    "MAX_WEIGHT"               NUMBER,
    "LOCATION_ID"              NUMBER(19,0),
    "IDX"                      NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    "INSERTTIME" TIMESTAMP (6),
    "UPDATETIME" TIMESTAMP (6),
    CONSTRAINT "TSL_RR_CONFIGURATION_LOCA_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("LOCATION_ID") REFERENCES "LOCATION" ("ID") ENABLE
  )
```

Using Hibernate One-to-many relation:following is my code to map the list

```
<list name="revRecov" table="TSL_RR_CONFIGURATION" cascade="all" access="field">
            <key column="LOCATION_ID"  />
            <index column="idx" />
            <one-to-many class="RevRecovery" />
        </list>
```

using spring form tags to show in a JSP form:

```
    <c:forEach items="${location.revRecov}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                <c:choose>          
                    <c:when test="${measureSys}">
                     <tr> <td><form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].trkType" /></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Max Length: 
                                <form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].maxLength" size="15" maxlength="14" />inches</td>
                            <td>Min Length: 
                                <form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].minLength" size="15" maxlength="14" />inches</td> 
                            </tr>
                             </c:when>
                             <c:otherwise>
                              <tr> <td><form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].trkType" /></td></tr>
                      <tr><td>Max Length: 
                       <form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].maxLength" size="15" maxlength="14" />cm</td>
                      <td>Min Length: 
                      <form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].minLength" size="15" maxlength="14" />cm</td></tr>
                   </c:otherwise>
                 </c:choose>
     </c:foreach>
```

Using `<c:when test>` tag to show the values either in inches or cm. My list has values something like

```
"97" "120" "5"
"12" "400" "1"
```

if it is 97, I have to show a label as Package and for 12, I should have pallet. Even when I validate it will be problem because, both the rows will be having different set of Max and Min values.

So, I was thinking, If I can make that list into two different lists and then pass it to JSP, I can validate as well.

What will be the best scenario to achieve it?If I divide into twolists is it going to be an issue when I save them to database?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated?

EDITED: In my case it solves the issue of different sets in the JSP, but it still remains validating an issue and what if I have more then 2 rows, I cannot use the index to show them in JSP for all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I can use the index of the row to show as different sets in the JSP
Instead of this: `<form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].maxLength" size="15" maxlength="14" />inches</td>`

used this:

```
<form:input path="revRecov[0].maxLength" size="15" maxlength="14" />inches</td>
<form:input path="revRecov[1].maxLength" size="15" maxlength="14" />inches</td>
```